# Update url using router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I have a router on my application now it respond as expected when I type in the url.  For exapmple if I type in www.example.com#search/groupa, I get the appropriate result back.  I have attempted in the search feature to call navigate to set the url so that a user could cut and paste that and send it to another user.  The issue is it doesnt work I get the following error when attempting to do so: "Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'navigate'"

```
IEG = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

IEG.addRegions({
searchBox: '#searchBox',
resultBox: '#resultBox',
modalBox: '#modalBox',
recipientBox: '#recipientBox',
confirmBox: '#confirmToggleActive'
});

IEG.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);


IEG.vent.on("default", function () {

var SBV = new SearchBoxView();
IEG.searchBox.show(SBV);
IEG.searchColl = new GroupEntries();
IEG.searchColl.fetch({
    data: {
        cmd: 0, //search groups
        searchStr: null //if null show all groups
    },
    success: function (data) {
        searchResults = new SearchResultsView({ collection: IEG.searchColl });
        IEG.resultBox.show(searchResults);
    }
});
});

IEG.vent.on("searchGroups", function (searchStr) {
IEG.Router.navigate("search" + searchStr);   // CALLING NAVIGATE HERE
IEG.searchColl.fetch({
    data: {
        cmd: 0, //search groups
        searchStr: searchStr
    },
    success: function (data) {
        searchResults = new SearchResultsView({ collection: IEG.searchColl });
        IEG.resultBox.show(searchResults);
    }
});
});

IEG.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'search/:str': 'search',
    'edit/:grp': 'edit'
},

index: function () {
    IEG.vent.trigger("default");
},

search: function (str)
{
    IEG.vent.trigger("searchGroups",str);
}
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    IEG.start();
    new IEG.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `navigate` on the instance of the `Router` class and not on its definition (as you're currently doing). Try updating the code in your document ready handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    IEG.start();
    IEG.router = new IEG.Router(); // Store an instance of the router on the Application
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

And your `searchGroups` handler like this:

```
IEG.vent.on("searchGroups", function (searchStr) {
     IEG.router.navigate("search" + searchStr);   // call navigate on the instance

     // Fetch code .....
});
```